# Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'telerik.web.ui.dll'

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have an older web forms application that has been upgraded to .Net framework 4.5.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and currently have Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q1 2016 installed.  When I open this solution I am greeted with the following error:

> Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'telerik.web.ui.dll'.  Cannot find assembly 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q1 2015\Bin45\Telerik.Web.UI.dll'

The same warning appears for "Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll"

When I try to build or rebuild the solution I receive multiple errors all complaining about Telerik.

I've double checked the web config against Telerik's documentation and everything seems to be working fine.  This solution builds fine on a co worker's computer who has not updated to the latest Telerik.  I've run the Telerik Toolbox Configuation Wizard in Admin mode.

Does anyone know what I can do to make this application work with the latest Telerik?

Comment: So, do you have the assembly in the specified Bin45 folder? 
If no, just download it from the site and put it there, or just reference it from a folder that is inside the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the Telerik references from the project
2. Copy the needed assemblies with the desired version to the BIN folder of your web app/site
3. Add references to them by pointing them to the BIN folder explicitly
4. Update the project in the source control system

Basically, follow the manual upgrade process here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/upgrading-instructions/upgrading-a-trial-to-a-developer-license-or-to-a-newer-version#manual-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

rdmptn's answer works if you don't need to periodically update the Telerik DLLs.  On the same page as the link he provided, there is another option to set up a more automatic reference:

> ## [Automatic Upgrade](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/upgrading-instructions/upgrading-a-trial-to-a-developer-license-or-to-a-newer-version#automatic-upgrade)
>
> You can utilize the AJAX VS Extensions wizards:
>
> 1. [Automatic Latest Version Retrieval Wizard](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/integration-with-visual-studio/visual-studio-extensions/automatic-latest-version-retrieval)
> 2. [Upgrade Wizard](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/integration-with-visual-studio/visual-studio-extensions/upgrade-wizard)

I personally find the Upgrade Wizard to be easier to use, especially since it works to update your project to refer to the Telerik library, without requiring an internet connection.  In summary from the page, the prerequisites are

1. the desired version of Telerik library is installed
2. the Telerik VS extension is installed

Then in the main VS menu,

- Telerik
- UI for ASP.NET AJAX
- Upgrade Wizard